# How to Call external JavaScript file in View in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a script folder in MVC and added a script file.  Now I want to call this script file where I have added all the functionality in my view.

For now all function of jQuery I am adding into view script section, but I want to do it with a separate JavaScript file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can import your js files in your HTML (index.html) with script tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-javascript-file.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have added also <script src="~/Scripts/ProductMaster.js" type="text/javascript"></script> but this not enough to call the script file

Comment: It should be. Is the path to the file correct?

Comment: Your called this script in your html file ?

Comment: if your tree folders is :

index.html

Scripts/
--> ProductMaster.js

So :

in index.html put =>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/ProductMaster.js"></script>
```


And use your function =>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  MyFunctionInProductMaster(argument)
</script>
```